# Create box between characters feet

Tags: python, animation

This is a question about how you would go about solving a problem, I'm new to Blender so unfamiliar with what approach I should use

I've imported an fbx file of a rigged human. The human is animated and is walking around.
[image]

What I want to be able to do is draw a box on the ground which will go around his feet when he moves. Like so:

[image: I drew box by hand]

Why am I doing this? This is for biomechanics - If the person's centre of gravity is in that box, they will be stable, if it goes outside they will tip over. I want to see that box as the subject moves.

Questions:

1. What is the best way in Blender to calculate that box? I could base it off of the mesh or the armature. I don't mind if its a a simple 4 sided boxes or something more complex which maps around the foot exactly generated off the mesh
2. What is the best way to animate that as the person moves?
3. For bonus points, if the person picks up their foot I'd the box to just map around the 1 foot they are standing on. Is there a way to do that? (I can use height off the ground z=0 to know if they are in contact with the ground.)

I don't need a working solution, just how you'd approach it. I'm adding this to a plugin I'm writing, so even if several steps are needed if you did it manually I can script it.

Comment: do you mean like this or has the box to be rotated as well? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc3cn.gif

Comment: That is very much what I'm trying to achieve. However as you say, in that video the 'foot box' is rectangular. I really want it to be a quadrilateral just mapping the space between the 2 feet.

Everything else is good though. The box moving with the character is just what I want to do.